# Flutter how to show 3 slider

Tags: flutter

Flutter i need to show slider image like this

[image]

I use Carouselslide butnot able to achieve same like as i show

my code is

```
Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: CarouselSlider(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  disableCenter: true,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  viewportFraction: 0.7,
                  enlargeCenterPage: false,
                  height: Height * 0.21,
                ),
                items: list
                    .map((item) => Container(
                  child: Image.asset(item),
                ))
                    .toList(),
              )),
```

Its showing like this

[image]

I need to show as show in above image. Or is it not possible by Carousel slider ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0, top: 0),
      child: Container(
          child: CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
               height: Height * 0.21,
              autoPlay: true,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              disableCenter: true,
              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                
            ),
            items: list
                .map((item) => Container(
              child: Image.network(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 400),
            ))
                .toList(),
          )),
    )
```

Comment: its showing too much padding in left side. how to remove left side gap ?